# Apache redirectmatch is wrongly be applied to other vhosts

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, virtualhost

I am using Apache 2.4.6 on Centos 7.4 and I have the following vhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

What I want is a rule that I can apply to all of my vhosts that redirects them to https (except for one mentioned below that needs to be on an unencrypted connection).

The problem is that I have another vhost that is being redirected to example.com which doesn't have any such rule and isn't supposed to be redirected. Help me understand what is going on here please? Does this mean I have to be careful about other rules like Header set? For example I don't want to set a HSTS preload header that's meant for one vhost on another vhost that isn't supposed to have that header.

Edit: My server is (poorly) managed so I had assumed that there was already a vhost setup for my other domain (the one that was redirecting when it shouldn't have been, let's call it example2.com) but it turns out there wasn't one. Adding a .conf file for example2.com was what I needed to fix the problem. It still doesn't explain to me why it was happening since the redirect should have been isolated to example.com, but at least it wasn't happening anymore.

Comment: BTW instead of RedirectMatch, you can just use `Redirect 301 / https://example.com/`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Name-based Virtual Host Support section of the Apache httpd manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html#alg):

> #### The default name-based vhost for an IP and port combination
>
> If no matching ServerName or ServerAlias is found in the set of virtual hosts containing the most specific matching IP address and port combination, then **the first listed virtual host** that matches that will be used.

Ie, it's generally a good idea to have a neutral first entry that is intended for the scenario that you get unexpected requests at some point.